# Doctor's mistake and homicide

Tags: reward-punishment, murder, talmud-bavli, intent-accident-purposely, maseches-makos

The *mishnah* in *Makkos* (beginning of 2nd chapter) teaches that if the person inadvertently killed someone through performing a *mitzvah*, the murder is exempt from the punishment of exile, which I believe the *Gemara* specifies to mean that he is *karov le-oneis* (i.e. it is considered an accident and he is absolved from responsibility).

One of the examples the *mishnah* brings is the *shaliach beis din* (court emissary) that has to whip someone sentenced by the court to lashes. In such a case, if he hits him, and the victim dies, the emissary is absolved from exile. Note that there is a medical doctor there to determine whether the criminal can withstand lashes, and how many.

My question is, even though the actual action is performed by the emissary, I would think that the true cause of death is the doctor, who misjudged the medical condition of the victim, permitting the extra blows that killed him. That is certainly more than a mere accident, it boundaries on negligence.

What happens to the doctor? I would think that since the *mishna* does not describe him, his fate is easier than the emissary's (who does the action causing the killing) and so the doctor is free to go -- but why is that reasonable, given that it was his decision which killed the victim?

Comment: What would you want to happen to the doctor? He didn't do an action, so we can't try him for formal murder with capital punishment.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, but his decision led to an inevitable action. I suppose I'm trying to argue that the shaliach here is almost like a computer - but the daas belongs to the doctor. After all, if the doctor programmed a robot to kill someone, we would certainly hold him responsible, even though he didn't do anything that directly caused death...

Comment: Hold him responsible to what? You want to have him executed? Also, generally speaking computers and people with brains are very different creatures in terms of "shlichut".

Comment: You cannot have him executed -- it was not premeditated murder, but why not have him responsible for the death in some way? Like send him to galus, for example.

Comment: @DoubleAA Also I understand that shlichus is different for people and computers - but here the person is Shaliach Bes Din, not Shaliach of a doctor -- and when the doctor ok's the whipping, the blows could be assumed to automatically happen...

Comment: Why would the doctor go to galus? Isn't he also serving in the performance of a mitzva?

Comment: @DoubleAA The question had 2 parts. (a) I speculated that the doctor is karuv leoneis, but did not know and wanted to find out. (b) if he is indeed karuv leoneis, why is this justified when he exhibited criminal professional negligence?

You just repeated (a)...

Comment: Only after you suggested that he would go to galus: "You cannot have him executed -- it was not premeditated murder, but why not have him responsible for the death in some way? Like send him to galus, for example." Basically I'm not sure what you are expecting to possibly happen. You're looking for "justified" and "reasonable" without any indication of how it could possibly be better.